# How to wrap html tag for jquery mouseup selection wrods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getselection, mouseup

I have reference the answer here [Select whole word with getSelection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380190/select-whole-word-with-getselection). I would like to make a `mouseup` selection `completed words` from `body`. than wrap `<p>` tag for the `selection words`. Here is the code. So how to? Thanks.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
(function($) {
function getSelected() {
  if(window.getSelection) { return window.getSelection(); }
  else if(document.getSelection) { return document.getSelection(); }
  else {
    var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();
    if(selection.text) { return selection.text; }
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}

function expand(range) {
    if (range.collapsed) {
        return;
    }

    while (range.toString()[0].match(/\w/)) {
        range.setStart(range.startContainer, range.startOffset - 1);   
    }

    while (range.toString()[range.toString().length - 1].match(/\w/)) {
        range.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset + 1);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').mouseup(function() {
    var selectionRange = getSelected().getRangeAt(0);
    var start = selectionRange.startOffset; 
    expand(selectionRange);
    var selection = selectionRange.toString();
    if(selection && (selection = new String(selection).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''))) {
        //how to wrap <p> tag for the selection words?
    }
  });
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
<style>
p {color:blue; }
</style>
<body>
Facebook needs to scrape your page to know how to display it around the site.

Facebook scrapes your page every 24 hours to ensure the properties are up to date. The page is also scraped when an admin for the Open Graph page clicks the Like button and when the URL is entered into the Facebook URL Linter. Facebook observes cache headers on your URLs - it will look at "Expires" and "Cache-Control" in order of preference. However, even if you specify a longer time, Facebook will scrape your page every 24 hours.

The user agent of the scraper is: "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"
</body>
```

UPDATE:

```
var new_html = $('body').html().split(selection, 1)[0] + '<p>' + selection + '</p>' + $('body').html().split(selection, 2)[1];
$('body').html(new_html);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(function($) {
function getSelected() {
  if(window.getSelection) { return window.getSelection(); }
  else if(document.getSelection) { return document.getSelection(); }
  else {
    var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();
    if(selection.text) { return selection.text; }
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}

function expand(range) {
    if (range.collapsed) {
        return;
    }

    while (range.toString()[0].match(/\w/)) {
        range.setStart(range.startContainer, range.startOffset - 1);   
    }

    while (range.toString()[range.toString().length - 1].match(/\w/)) {
        range.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset + 1);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').mouseup(function() {
    var selectionRange = getSelected().getRangeAt(0);
    var start = selectionRange.startOffset; 
    expand(selectionRange);
    var selection = selectionRange.toString();
    if(selection && (selection = new String(selection).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''))) {
        var el = $('body');
        el.html(el.html().replace(selection, "<p>"+selection+"</p>"));    }
  });
});
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CHhJG/

Comment: @Giberno: Really? String replacement in the `innerHTML` of the whole body is a terrible way to do this. It won't work in any case where the selection crosses element boundaries, it will replace all existing elements in the body and thus lose any existing event handlers, it will not necessarily produce valid HTML and it will be slow.

Comment: @Tim Down, em... I am careless to check out this problem. this will replace first word in the whole body, not the selection words. I search about `word selection questions` in stackoverflow, you are expert in this section. so do you have any good idea to do a right anwser? many thanks.

Comment: @Tim Down, hi, friend, good evening r u still here? I guess u have already got a wonderful answer, haven't u?

Comment: @Giberno: It's not trivial to handle in the general case. You'd need to split existing paragraphs at the start and end of the selection to do this properly. The most helpful way to think about it is in terms of the operations you need to perform to the DOM tree.

Comment: Thanks, @Tim Down, so I think may be I should make another function

Comment: hi, @Tim Down, I have some ugly code, in my `question` `update` part. this will make a `spilt` will full html and finally reach my goal. do you have further advice, hot to match out the `selection` dom part instead the full html? Thanks.