# Building a :selection selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I query (in a jQuery sense) the DOM elements - *not* just text nodes - completely selected by the mouse?

Comment: What does "highlight" mean exactly? And, even more so, what does "partially highlight" mean?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803016/how-to-wrap-html-tag-for-jquery-mouseup-selection-wrods/7803559#7803559

Comment: @Randomblue "selected" is the more familiar term for that...

Comment: @Randomblue Consider `:selection`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Good idea! I'll edit the question.

Comment: Have a look at the [`window.getSelection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getSelection) method. I'm heading off, so I cannot post the full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you all the elements that are completely selected:

```
var currentSelection = window.getSelection();
var firstRangeInSelection = currentSelection.getRangeAt(0);
var commonAncestor = firstRangeInSelection.commonAncestorContainer;

var nodesInSelection = $(commonAncestor).find("*").filter(function() {
                           return currentSelection.containsNode(this, false);
                       });
```

For more info on DOM Selections, check out [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsISelection).

Comment: +1, although it would be improved by a few checks: first, IE < 9 does not support `window.getSelection()` so you should check for the existence of that; second, `getRangeAt(0)` will throw an error if nothing is selected, so you should check the `currentSelection.rangeCount` is greater than zero.

Comment: Actually, what happens if the selection is completely contained within a single text node? I presume you'll get an empty jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

You could adapt my answer to the following question to return you a jQuery object rather than an array, which should be simple:

[JS: Get array of all selected nodes in contentEditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781963/js-get-array-of-all-selected-nodes-in-contenteditable-div/7784176#7784176)

However, this won't work in IE < 9, which does not support the same `Selection` object as other browsers. For that, you'll need another approach. There is my own [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) library, as mentioned in that answer, but if you need IE < 9 support without a library then I can knock something together.

Comment: @Chris: I wasn't referring to your answer. I had assumed the OP would want a jQuery collection rather than an array, which is what the answer of mine I linked to produces.