# HTML browser "text" selection: select whole words (like in iBooks)

Tags: javascript, html, css, selection

I have a structure:

```
<span class="word">This</span><span class="word">is</span><span class="word">the</span><span class="word">text</span><span>.</span>
```

I want user to be able to make a selection of whole words (spans, class="words") (in browser on desktop and on iOS as well - like in iBooks).

And how can I style it with css?

What is the right way to do this? (didn't work with selections before)

Thanks.

Comment: How do you mean "make a selection of whole words"? What should happen when they select a word, and how do they select a word - click it? highlight it?

Comment: A menu would appear ontop of the selection.

Comment: Related SO page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809319/get-selected-text-expanded-to-whole-words

Comment: Something like a [tooltip](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/)?

Comment: I still don't really understand. The user makes a text selection in the normal way (mouse drag, etc.), yes? Then what needs to happen?

Comment: Did you see iBooks or kindle on iPad? User may tap on a screen and it will select one word, then the selection can be extended to nearest words. I need to do this in browser HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I know you didn't mention jQuery - but with something this dynamic I think it is highly advisable to use it.

Wrap that whole deal in a div.

```
<div id="wordSelector"><spans></div>
```

And then attach a mousedown event to the div. Use a semaphore to ensure that events are handled only during mousedown. Capture mouseover events on the spans until the mouseup event is registered.

Note: These events may need to be attached to document instead of the div to ensure that a mousedown event outside of the div but entering the div is handled, and with mouseup as well in case the mouseup event is outside of the div.

```
var spansTouched = [];
var mouseDown = 0;
$("#wordSelector").mousedown( function(){
 //track spans touched with a semaphore
 mouseDown++;
});
$("#wordSelector").mouseup( function(){
 mouseDown = 0;
 //handle spansTouched and then reset it to []
});
$(".word").mouseover( function(){
 if(mouseDown > 0){
  spansTouched.push(this);
 }
});
```

Obviously there is room for improvement here, this is just to highlight a possible approach to take using a semaphore and mouse events.

Comment: It won't work on iOS by default (to make such solution work I need to handle touch and tap events, not mouse)

Comment: @WHITECOLOR - When using a mobile browser on iOS, a touch event counts as a mousedown event. Dragging is synonymous to mouseover, and mouseup is when the touch event stops. Did you do any testing?

Comment: Yes mouseover event is not drag on iPad (https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html). That is why i'm looking for "standard solution", not via events handling. It should work. It work in amazon kindle cloud reader (its HTML5 ebook reader)

Comment: @WHITECOLOR - From that link: "the flow of events generated by one-finger and two-finger gestures are conditional depending on whether or not the selected element is clickable or scrollable" .... "A clickable element is a link, form element, image map area, or any other element with mousemove, mousedown, mouseup, or onclick handlers". Perhaps mousemove instead of mouseover but the point remains - the "touch" events are mouse events as clearly stated in that apple dev documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you mean that the user should select a word. If the user should "select" a word by clicking on it, you could use a jQuery plugin like [TipTip](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin) or any other [tooltip-plugin](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/). At least tiptip support click.

Not sure if any of the tooltip-plugins support triggering on highlight of text by default, but using a JavaScript to listen for highlighting of text and the trigger the appropriate tooltip to show manually, and hide it again if the text is deselected.

Dave Welsh has written a [small piece of jQuery](http://davidwalsh.name/text-selection-ajax) to sniff for text-selection, that could be utilized.

Comment: I need also that selection to work on iOS (tablets), will it work? I don't need tooltip, just a selection that works on iOS as well.

Comment: @WHITECOLOR Just tried it on my iPad, and unfortunately it doesn't seem to work very well on it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yes mouseover event is not drag on iPad. That is why i'm looking for standard solution. It should work. It work in amazon kindle cloud reader (its HTML5 ebook reader)

Comment: @WHITECOLOR Then the easiest way is probably to have a look at their code for inspiration.

Comment: This is definitely not the easiest way)