# What does the range.expand() function do in JS?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, range, expand, textrange

As far as I understand, this function is non-standard, but even for non-standard functions it was usually possible to find at least some description in the same MDN Web Docs, for example for the function [`document.caretRangeFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/caretRangeFromPoint). But for `range.expand` there is nothing at all, not only in the reference book, but also on the Internet at all, and the IDE does not recognize it, it is not in the auto-completion list (the same *caretRangeFromPoint* is in the list, although it is crossed out and marked as deprecated). But at the same time, `range.expand` definitely works at least in chrome, and I even managed to find its mentions on stackowerflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3710561) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809319/get-selected-text-expanded-to-whole-words)). Also, as far as I understand, this function also works or worked in the IE browser. I managed to find a small [description](https://learn-javascript-ru.translate.goog/range-textrange-selection?_x_tr_sl=ru&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=ru&_x_tr_pto=wapp#textrange-dlya-ie) for the version of the function for IE (`textRange.expand()`) (the link was run through Google translator, so it may become outdated over time), however, not all the behavior described there works in chrome - for example, of the four argument options described there, the function accepted only two - “word” and “sentence”.

So what does it do? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant, sorry for my bad english

Comment: There is a big red notice at the top of the `document.caretRangeFromPoint()` page that states: _"**Non-standard:** This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future."_. I doubt the IDE would recommend something that you shouldn't use; or at least show you a warning that the method shouldn't be used.

Comment: I found http://help.dottoro.com/ljikhvui.php which documents it as IE-only and https://github.com/whatwg/dom/issues/431 about standardisation efforts

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl That's not what the question is about. It's just an example that even obsolete and deprecated methods *normally* are still documented on MDN

Comment: The non-standard stuff documented in MDN tends to be Mozilla features and things that were implemented in a few different browsers, but were then abandoned. If this was just IE, they might not have bothered documenting it there.