# How do I extend selection to word boundary using JavaScript, once only?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, selection

I'm using the technique shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7381574/1309774) to extend a web page's selection to a word boundary:

```
function snapSelectionToWord() {
    var sel;

    // Check for existence of window.getSelection() and that it has a
    // modify() method. IE 9 has both selection APIs but no modify() method.
    if (window.getSelection && (sel = window.getSelection()).modify) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (!sel.isCollapsed) {

            // Detect if selection is backwards
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.setStart(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
            range.setEnd(sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);
            var backwards = range.collapsed;
            range.detach();

            // modify() works on the focus of the selection
            var endNode = sel.focusNode, endOffset = sel.focusOffset;
            sel.collapse(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
            if (backwards) {
                sel.modify("move", "forward", "word");
                sel.extend(endNode, endOffset);
                sel.modify("extend", "backward", "word");

            } else {
                sel.modify("move", "backward", "word");
                sel.extend(endNode, endOffset);
                sel.modify("extend", "forward", "word");
            }
        }
    } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        var textRange = sel.createRange();
        if (textRange.text) {
            textRange.expand("word");
            // Move the end back to not include the word's trailing space(s),
            // if necessary
            while (/\s$/.test(textRange.text)) {
                textRange.moveEnd("character", -1);
            }
            textRange.select();
        }
    }
}​
```

So far, so good.  But if you call the `snapSelectionToWord` function more than once on the selection, it's expanded outward by one word in both directions on each call, which is not good if you want to call it more than once while text is selected.

Here's a [live jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/inactivist/NSdXZ/) that allows you to repeatedly click a 'Snap' button, which demonstrates the problem.

How can the original solution be fixed so that it doesn't expand the selection if it's already on a word boundary?

- I'd prefer to leave a comment on the [original solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7381574/1309774) but, sadly, I've not yet been graced with sufficient karma by the StackOverflow karma brigade--otherwise, I'd just ask there.  And I'm not sure how to fix the problem, so I won't edit the original solution.

Edit: Adding code snippet per request

Comment: Please put all relevant code in this post instead of linking to it.

Comment: Done.  Still learning StackOverflow etiquette.

Comment: I've updated the original solution with Matt M's change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe try popping a character off in either direction before you snap to words:

```
        if (backwards) {
            sel.modify("move", "backward", "character");
            sel.modify("move", "forward", "word");
            sel.extend(endNode, endOffset);
            sel.modify("extend", "forward", "character");
            sel.modify("extend", "backward", "word");

        } else {
            sel.modify("move", "forward", "character");
            sel.modify("move", "backward", "word");
            sel.extend(endNode, endOffset);
            sel.modify("extend", "backward", "character");
            sel.modify("extend", "forward", "word");
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3RAkZ/

Comment: +1. Work on Google Chrome. Here is a smaller version that removed these redundant code: http://jsfiddle.net/3RAkZ/1/

Comment: Thanks.  Works in Chrome here, too.  I'll try other browsers and report back.

Comment: This does share the compatibility problems of the original code: it doesn't work at all in Opera, and there are some differences between what constitutes a word between browsers.

Comment: In some cases (in Chrome), this solution extends the end of the selection by an extra word.  Investigating...

Comment: onfortunately, like in other examples I've found on stackoverflow, it fails when you have `1 + 1` or `1 ++ 1` string, and try to select just `+` or `++` - it selects surrounding characters as well (and spaces between them) - is there an easy way to check final result (e.g. `sel.toString().indexOf(' ') > -1`) and then select only characters between spaces?

Answer (score 10):

I wrote that sample. I've never been happy with it, for the reason you point out, and also because it doesn't work consistently in all browsers (or at all in Opera).

I've been working on a cross-browser solution to this for my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) library. The current release is described as an alpha but it works pretty well. Here's a demo:

http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/textrange.html

And here's your demo, modified to use Rangy:

http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/RgZ8r/

The crucial line is

```
rangy.getSelection().expand("word");
```

If you don't want to use something as heavyweight as Rangy (it's something like 50KB of code to use the TextRange module) then it's possible to improve the original code (as Matt M has in his answer) but it will still have limitations.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I'll check out your updated solution.

Comment: I have made a slight modification to the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dux4fqhL/1/. It checks if the selection is collapsed before expanding, otherwise it may have some undesirable effects when selecting nothing.

Comment: That link is broken

Answer (score 1):

your code does not work properly in arabic text 
you can try this snippet nstead

```js
function snapSelectionToWord() {
    var sel;

    // Check for existence of window.getSelection() and that it has a
    // modify() method. IE 9 has both selection APIs but no modify() method.
    if (window.getSelection && (sel = window.getSelection()).modify) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.isCollapsed) {
           
           var rng2 = sel.getRangeAt(0);
           var startOffset = rng2.startOffset;
           startOffset = 0
           for (var i = rng2.startOffset; i >= 0; i--) {
              if (rng2.startContainer.data[i].match(/\S/) != null) {
                 startOffset++;
              } else
                 break;
           }
           var endOffset = rng2.endOffset;
           endOffset = 0;
           for (var i = rng2.endOffset; i < rng2.endContainer.data.length; i++)
              if (rng2.endContainer.data[i].match(/\S/)) {
                 endOffset++;
              } else
                 break;

           startOffset = rng2.startOffset - startOffset;
           startOffset = startOffset < 0 ? 0 : startOffset;

           endOffset = rng2.endOffset + endOffset;
           endOffset = endOffset >= rng2.endContainer.data.length ? rng2.endContainer.data.length - 1 : endOffset;

           rng2.setStart(rng2.startContainer, startOffset);
           rng2.setEnd(rng2.endContainer, endOffset);
           sel.removeAllRanges();
           sel.addRange(rng2);
           
        }
    } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        var textRange = sel.createRange();
        if (textRange.text) {
            textRange.expand("word");
            // Move the end back to not include the word's trailing space(s),
            // if necessary
            while (/\s$/.test(textRange.text)) {
                textRange.moveEnd("character", -1);
            }
            textRange.select();
        }
    }
}
```