# Selection to word boundaries, but excluding punctuation signs

Tags: javascript, html, dom, selection

I try to modify the selection a user has done to always be complete words. For example, given the Text "Report: President Obama seeks to keep 9,800 US troops in Afghanistan...after this year, source says", if as user just selects "fghanist" I would like that the selection modifies to "Afghanistan". After some searching I stumbled, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964016/how-do-i-extend-selection-to-word-boundary-using-javascript-once-only) on Stackoverflow, upon the following solution:

```
snapSelectionToWord : function() {
  var sel;
  if (window.getSelection && (sel = window.getSelection()).modify) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
        // Detect if selection is backwards
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
        range.setEnd(sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);

        var backwards = range.collapsed;
        range.detach();

        // modify() works on the focus of the selection
        var endNode = sel.focusNode, endOffset = sel.focusOffset;
        sel.collapse(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);

        var direction = [];
        if (backwards) {
            direction = ['backward', 'forward'];
        } else {
            direction = ['forward', 'backward'];
        }

        sel.modify("move", direction[0], "character");
        sel.modify("move", direction[1], "word");
        sel.extend(endNode, endOffset);
        sel.modify("extend", direction[1], "character");
        sel.modify("extend", direction[0], "word");
    }
  } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
      var textRange = sel.createRange();
      if (textRange.text) {
        textRange.expand("word");
        // Move the end back to not include the word's trailing space(s), if necessary
        while (/\s$/.test(textRange.text)) {
            textRange.moveEnd("character", -1);
        }
        textRange.select();
    }
  }
},
```

In principle, it works pretty well. However, there are some pathelogical cases. For examle, the selection "fghanistan.." it snaps to "Afghanistan...after" (I would like to have "Afghanistan"). The same result I get for selection ".afte" (desired result here: "after"). The main problem seems to be that the granularity `word` only considers whitespace but not other punctuation marks.

My idea was now to change the granularity from `word` to `character` and put this into a loop until a punctuation signs is reached. This works pretty well for the `sel.modify("extend", ...);` lines, but not (as intended) for the `sel.modify("move", ...);` lines. Both after the `collapse` and the first `move` modification, `sel.toString()` is empty. Hence, I cannot loop of the first/last character to move character by character. After `sel.extend(endNode, endOffset);`, `sel.toString()` is set again, and the approach using a loop works.

I simply cannot get my head around this.

Comment: Applications that auto–select entire words drive me crazy. Be aware that some users will seriously hate this. :-)

Comment: RobG, agreed! I don't like to be patronized either :). However, I'm aiming for a system where users annotate text snippets. That is, they first select a snippet and then can annotate it. I think snapping to word boundaries is reasonable in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon [rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/), which solves my issues pretty well. Using this library reduces my function to:

```
snapSelectionToWord : function() {
  rangy.getSelection().expand("word");
},
```

Thanks and kudos to the developer for making my life so much easier!