# how to modify selection from left to right white space

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

in the example below pls place the cursor inside `story`, for example after the letter `b`.

When clicking on the button I need to expand the selection left AND right untill a white space - or start/end of line.
so `https://tumblr.com` should be selected and written in console.

problem with my trying - only `tumblr` is selected

```js
$(btngo).on('click', function(){
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.modify("move", "backward", "word");
    sel.modify("extend", "right", "word");
    console.log(sel.toString()); // tumblr - I need - https://tumblr.com
});
```

```css
.story{outline:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='story' id='story' contenteditable>
lorem - https://tumblr.com
</div>
<br>
<button id='btngo'>GO</button>
```

Comment: [MDN getSelection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) *Returns: A Selection object.   When cast to string, either by appending an empty string ("") or using Selection.toString(), this object returns the text selected.*

Comment: @freedomn-m- thanks I see, but how to get the whole desired selection

Comment: I realise that's not an answer, it's addressing your `console.log(sel)`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/extend may shed some light:  *The anchor of the selection does not move. The selection will be from the anchor to the new focus, regardless of direction.* - which is exactly what's happening when you use .modify("extend")

Comment: Use .modify("move".. to move the caret then extend it:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10964743/2181514

Comment: If you want something other than the [provided selections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/modify) (granularity) - then you'll need to get the text yourself, locate the selection and expand it with your own code, eg using a regex or [lastIndexOf(" ", start)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

Comment: @freedomn-m - strange there is no `space` as granularity option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Javascript [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) and [Selection.setBaseAndExtent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/setBaseAndExtent):

*This solution starts with the [`anchorNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/anchorNode) and [`focusNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/focusNode) to locate the cursor, then [Selection.setBaseAndExtent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/setBaseAndExtent) to gradually expand the selection until whitespace is found. The benefit to this approach is speed and performance are not affected by the size of the text block the cursor is placed in.*

Place cursor within any word, and click "GO".

The forward side of the selection, typically the `anchorNode` (starting) position, is moved backward incrementally until a space or line return is found. The backward side of the selection, typically the `focusNode` (ending) position, is moved forward incrementally until a space or line return is found. That selection text is now available for further processing as `sel.toString()`.

> Actually, the `anchorNode` and `anchorOffset` are where the users
> start their cursor selection, and the `focusNode` and `focusOffset`
> is where they end their selection. So the `anchor...` is typically
> before, and the `focus...` after, but not necessarily. So these are
> sorted in order to move them in the corresponding direction they were
> selected.

```js
document.getElementById("btngo").addEventListener('click', function () { // vanilla...why not?
    const sel = window.getSelection();

    let [bws,aws] = [false,false]; // before whitespace, after whitespace

    // sort because direction user makes selection determines node/offset order
    let [[bn,bo],[an,ao]] // before node/offset (backward), and after node/offset (forward)
        = [[sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset],[sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset]]
            .sort(function (aa,bb) { return aa[1] - bb[1]; }); // sort by offset

    // move BEFORE position backward until whitespace or beginning of node
    while ( !bws && 0 < bo ) {
        sel.setBaseAndExtent(bn,--bo,an,ao); // move backward 1 character

        // don't include whitespace, and assign result to bws
        if ( (bws = (-1 !== sel.toString().search(/\r?\n| /))) ) {
            ++bo; // prepare to move forward 1 to remove space
        }
    }

    // move AFTER position forward until whitespace or end of node
    while ( !aws && an.length >= ao + 1 ) {
        sel.setBaseAndExtent(bn,bo,an,++ao); // move forward 1 character
        if ( (aws = (-1 !== sel.toString().search(/\r?\n| /))) ) { // don't include whitespace, and assign result to aws
            --ao; // prepare to move backward to remove space
        }
    }
    sel.setBaseAndExtent(bn,bo,an,ao); // remove whitespace
    console.log(sel.toString());
});
```

```css
.story{outline:none;}
```

```html
<div class="story" id="story" contenteditable>
lorem - https://tumblr.com
more text to@select from
</div>
<br>
<button id="btngo">GO</button>
```

Comment: finally that's it. Thanks again. Solved

Comment: I see just now - it doesn't work if cursor is in last word (from)

Comment: In the "Run code snippet" I put the cursor in "from" and it gets highlighted and logged. It doesn't for you?

Comment: no, it doesn't. Placing cursor inside `from` and clicking on `go` my page becomes unresponsive (chrome, don't know for other browsers). Seems the code fals into some kind of endless circular execution.

Comment: Good catch. I found the problem and fixed it. Apparently chrome wasn't letting the `try`/`catch` block suppress the focusOffset error. Now using this check: `sel.focusNode.length >= sel.focusOffset + 1` to make sure the error doesn't occur.

Comment: it works. You're a javascript hero !  Any idea - how to suggest to js developers something like `selection.modify("extend", "left and right", "url");` - meaning - give me the url under the current cursor position. The entire story here would be - a single line of code

Comment: Cool. `selection.modify("extend", /regex/)` might be more practical.

Answer (score 1):

Using Javascript [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection), [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) and [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

*This solution splits the entire block of text into lines, then splits the line into words. It first searches line by line for the cursor position, then, once the line if found, searches the line for the word containing the cursor. The larger the text block the more processing is required to find and highlight the target word. For a [**solution independent of text block size**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72455523/2743458) see my other answer.*

Place cursor within any word, and click "GO". That word is returned for further processing, and highlighted. If the cursor is not placed in a word, or text is already selected, the block of text is not searched and the message "no cursor position" is returned.

To find the word, (a continuous string of characters without spaces), containing the cursor, the entire text block is split on spaces or line returns. This array is looped over searching for the cursor position. Once it is found the corresponding word in the array  is returned, and then used to locate the word in the block of text, which is then highlighted.

```js
// document.getElementById("btngo").addEventListener('click', function () { // vanilla

$(btngo).on('click', function(){
    var sel = window.getSelection();

    // get beginning and end of selection
    let ao = sel.anchorOffset;
    let fo = sel.focusOffset;

    // make sure there is a cursor position but not a selected range
    if ( 1 < fo && ao === fo ) {

        // get node containing cursor
        let fn = sel.focusNode;
        // trim whitespace at beginning and end of block of text, 
        // then split on spaces into an array
        let fn_arr = fn.textContent.trim().split(/\r?\n|\s/);

        // loop array and search for cursor position
        // when found use position to determine word in array containing cursor
        let [strt,end,wrd] = fn_arr.reduce(function (acc, txt) {

            return (fo > acc[1]) // have we reached the cursor position?
              ? [acc[1] + 1, acc[1] + txt.length + 1, txt] // if not keep track of location
              : acc; // if so, keep returning location information
        }, [0,0,""]);

        console.log(wrd); // display word containing cursor

        // select word containing cursor
        let range = new Range();
        range.setStart(fn, strt);
        range.setEnd(fn, end);
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
    else { console.log('no cursor position') }
});
```

```css
.story{outline:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='story' id='story' contenteditable>
lorem - https://tumblr.com
more text to@select from
</div>
<br>
<button id='btngo'>GO</button>
```

---

For a LONG block of text, it can be searched line by line, then search only the line for cursor:

```
document.getElementById("btngo").addEventListener('click', function () {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    // get beginning and end of selection
    let [ao, fo] = [sel.anchorOffset, sel.focusOffset];
    // make sure there is a cursor position but not a selected range
    if ( 1 < fo && ao === fo ) {
        // get node containing cursor
        let fn = sel.focusNode;

// FIND LINE
        // split on *line returns* into an array
        let fn_arr = fn.textContent.trim().split(/\r?\n/);
        // when found use position to determine *line* in array containing cursor
        let [strt,end,wrd] = fn_arr.reduce(findCursor(fo), [0,0,""]);

// FIND WORD IN LINE
        // split on *spaces* into an array
        fn_arr = wrd.trim().split(' ');    
        // when found use position to determine *word* in array containing cursor
        [strt,end,wrd] = fn_arr.reduce(findCursor(fo), [strt,strt-1,""]);

        console.log(wrd); // display word containing cursor
        // select word containing cursor
        let range = new Range();
        range.setStart(fn, strt);
        range.setEnd(fn, end);
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
    else { console.log('no cursor position')}
});

const findCursor = function (fo) {
    return function (acc, txt) {
        return (fo > acc[1]) // have we reached the cursor position?
            ? [acc[1] + 1, acc[1] + txt.length + 1, txt] // if not keep track of location
            : acc; // if so, keep returning location information
    }
}
```

Comment: what if entire text has 200k spaces ? It will loop over all of them ?

Comment: Sure, why not. I just ran a test with 55,751 words and 321,966 spaces.

Comment: thanks a lot for your idea and code. I will try. As I can see - it should work. I will upvote but wait with accepting, Still hope there is a cheaper solution

Comment: maybe somehow split by lines and find the current line and then split the current line by spaces

Answer (score 1):

You can use a range to position the cursor where you need it and select from there, in this case the selection will be from the 9th position up to the end of line.

```js
$(btngo).on('click', function(){
    var range = document.createRange()
    var sel = window.getSelection()
    
    //place the cursor to 9th position
    range.setStart($("#story")[0].childNodes[0], 9)
    range.collapse(true)
    
    sel.removeAllRanges()
    sel.addRange(range)  
 
    sel.modify("extend", "right", "lineboundary");
    console.log(sel.toString());
});
```

```css
.story{outline:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='story' id='story' contenteditable>
lorem - https://tumblr.com
</div>
<br>
<button id='btngo'>GO</div>
```

Comment: excellent. Pls explain why just `9` ? What if I have a long href ?

Comment: @provance The `https://tumblr.com` string starts at the 9th position and from there we can use `modify` to select.