# Text Seletion with markers for web browser

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, textselection

How to achevie the Text selection along with markers for web browsers (angular / Javascript code). Some thing like [UITextView text selection and highlight jumping in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454037/uitextview-text-selection-and-highlight-jumping-in-ios-8), but need to acheive in web browser. since I have not found any idea / hint on how to acheive this, here I am posting the question, any reference or idealogy would help, thanks

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript - How can i set markers for selected text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592837/javascript-how-can-i-set-markers-for-selected-text)

Comment: The  linked SO question contains working codepen. It only listens for mouse change, but you could hook up to  the `selectionchange` event to cover the keyboard selection as  well. Of course needs adding proper styling for markers as well.