# Extend Selection to complete Words

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following snippet to get the text of a selected/marked sentence 
How can I extend the selection to get the sentence with whole words? For example if the user starts and ends the selection within the words. Thank you for your tips.

**JS**

```
function selectHTML() {
    try {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            var c = document.selection.createRange();
            return c.htmlText;
        }

        var nNd = document.createElement("span");
        $('#helperDiv').val(nNd);
        var w = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

        w.surroundContents(nNd);
        return nNd.innerHTML;
    } catch (e) {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            return document.selection.createRange();
        } else {
            return getSelection();
        }
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yL6g6wvb/5/)

Comment: check out this answer -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380190/select-whole-word-with-getselection